# Программа для видеозахвата

Tags: c#, камера, протоколы

Задача такая. Необходимо создать приложение по наблюдению за кассирами.
Существует база данных с операциями по кассирам, пробитие чека,
аннулирование  и т.д.

1. Была задумка по определенной выборке находить необходимые события по
   кассе,
   далее по событию находить нужный фрагмент видео в архиве, т.е.
   ориентироваться по времени чека(события)
   и вставать на фрагмент этого места в видео файле
2. так же необходима возможность онлайн контроля процесса продажи.

Вопрос с чего начать, немного поискав понял что даже IP камеры несколько
протоколов,
а в наличии есть еще и аналоговые камеры...
Возможно есть смысл онлайн контроль осуществлять с помощью какой то
"бесплатной" готовой программы
настроить чтобы программа могла писать в какой нибудь определенный
распространенный формат AVI например.

А приложение уже писать самому и разбирать видео файлы, которые будут
создаваться бесплатной программой.

желательно писать на C#, есть опыт.

с помощью какой библиотеки можно подружить камеры протокола rtsp с приложением C#(показывать видео онлайн, и писать его в архив)?

Comment: В текущем виде на ваш вопрос невозможно дать лаконичный ответ. Для получения ответа поясните, **в чем именно вы видите проблему**, какие технологии используете **и что хотите видеть в ответе**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> с помощью какой библиотеки можно подружить камеры протокола rtsp с
>   приложением C#(показывать видео онлайн, и писать его в архив)?

Посмотрите [net7mma.codeplex.com](http://net7mma.codeplex.com/)

Проект активно развивается, и в сети довольно много упоминаний, включая EnSO, возможно эта библиотека перекроет ваши задачи.